# Does 4k supported graphical cards works on pci express 2.0?

Tags: pci-express, 4k-resolution

Is it possible for a motherboard supporting pci express 16x v2.0 max to display 4k resolution using a graphical card that works on v3.0 ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: PCI-e is backwards compatible. So a PCI-e v2 card will work in a PCI-e v3 slot. (Though only at v2.0 speeds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Because I suspected that a motherboard that support a version 2.0 max would not work with a graphical card with version 3.0 (incompatible versions, or reduced performances). In other words, what will be the results of this difference?

Comment: PCI Express v2.0 x16 slots are fast enough for even high end graphics card throughput. But I can give you a more precise answer if I know what graphics card, motherboard, and CPU we're talking about.

Comment: Cyril, these tests will probably be of interest: https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Impact-of-PCI-E-Speed-on-Gaming-Performance-518/

Comment: The motherboard is this one : http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3894#ov And I'm looking to buy the "cheapest but functionnal" graphical card. The main purpose will be work (web development), no game (ok well, maybe some flash game at most, no Crysis and cie). But I still need a good quality of image. That's why I'm asking these questions :)

Comment: @CyrilN. I don't see any reason you'd have an issue then.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Awesome! Thank you very much for your help :)